# Mapping between Swagger OpenAPI model and JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to map **openAPI model**(Generated using Swagger codegen) and **JPA Entity**(Generated from database schema in Hibernate) in my java REST-API, so that I can save received model into database using JPA(hibernate) entity and use model to create response for fetching data from database.

I know I can create use model and entity separately and create a mechanism to convert from one to another. However, if there is any change in database or field in model I need to update both model and entity which is cumbersome.

Is there any way to define model/entity such that it can be used in both Swagger and hibernate JPA? and does not required to create both of them(which is redundant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out the concept of DTO(Data Transfer Object) which can be mapped to your Model per your response to API call.

You can used ModelMapper or create a custom mapper to perform the conversion from Model to DTO.

you can use following package in spring boot(Gradle) for ModelMapper :

```
implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.0'
```